# $f, g \in D[a, b] \text{ AND } f(a) \ge g(a) \text{ AND } \forall x \in [a, b]: f'(x) \ge g'(x) \\ \text{ THEN } \forall x \in [a, b]: f(x) \ge g(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, inequality, terminology

There is this well-known rule, which helps one prove inequalities with derivatives:

$ \text{ IF } f, g \in D[a, b] \text{ AND } f(a) \ge g(a) \text{ AND } \forall x \in [a, b]: f'(x) \ge g'(x) \\\text{ THEN } \forall x \in [a, b]: f(x) \ge g(x) \text{.}$

Does it have some **specific** name? If so, what is it? If not, how is it most often referred to?

---

**Note:** We use $ DM $ denotes a set of all functions $f \text{ | } \forall x \in M: \text {there exists } f'(x) \text{.}$ Not sure how common it is among English-speakers.

Comment: So $f$ and $g$ are differentiable functions with domain $[a,b]$. I'm not sure if this theorem has a specific name. It is the same as saying: If $h(a) \geq 0$ and $h'(x) \geq 0 \forall x \in [a,b]$ then $h$ is non-negative, where $h(x) = (f-g)(x)$. This result is "fairly obvious", I would say.

Comment: @AdamRubinson true. I guess one may use just that if we do not find the name, yet it would be quite fun to keep the question up - no one knows what may pop up here.

Comment: I never said to close the question.

Comment: @AdamRubinson yeah, I just decided to point that out as I was not sure whether the question fitted the site in the first place. I brushed it off as "History and development of mathematics", yet it just doesn't seem right 100%.

Comment: I think asking about history or terminology is acceptable for this site.